# ibm-odm:IlrJ2SESessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, session, sessionfactory, ibm-bpm, ibm-odm

I am using the following code to create list of rules fires in **ODM** ,but eclipse is showing above compilation error.

```
package com.cper.brms.model.questions;

import ilog.rules.res.session.IlrSessionRequest;

import ilog.rules.res.session.IlrSessionResponse;

import ilog.rules.res.session.ruleset.IlrBusinessExecutionTrace;

import ilog.rules.res.session.ruleset.IlrExecutionTrace;

import ilog.rules.teamserver.auth.AuthenticationCredentials;

import ilog.rules.teamserver.model.IlrConnectException;

import ilog.rules.teamserver.model.IlrSession;

import ilog.rules.teamserver.model.IlrSessionFactory;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class RulesTrace<IlrStatelessSession>
{

    IlrSessionFactory sessionFactory = new IlrJ2SESessionFactory();

    IlrSessionRequest sessionRequest = sessionFactory.createRequest();
    String rulesetPath = "/miniloanruleapp/miniloanrules";
    }
    sessionRequest.setRulesetPath(IlrPath.parsePath(rulesetPath));

    sessionRequest.setTraceEnabled(true);
    sessionRequest.getTraceFilter().setInfoAllFilters(true);

    Map<String,Object> inputParameters = sessionRequest.getInputParameters();
    inputParameters.put("loan", loan);
    inputParameters.put("borrower", borrower);

    IlrStatelessSession session = sessionFactory.createStatelessSession();
    IlrSessionResponse response = session.execute(sessionRequest);

    IlrExecutionTrace sessionTrace = response.getRulesetExecutionTrace();
    int rulesNumber = sessionTrace.getTotalRulesFired(); 

    IlrBusinessExecutionTrace execResult = new IlrBusinessExecutionTrace(response.getRulesetExecutionTrace());
    List<String> rulesFired = execResult.getRuleFiredBusinessNames();
    loan = (Loan) response.getOutputParameters().get("loan"); 



}
```

Do I need to create any customized code to create sessionFactory or am i missing any jar?

Comment: Formatting code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the version mismatch causing the error.I have JAVAEE in my eclipse,but above code is for JavaSE. Changed the code to right version.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing jrules-res-execution.jar from your project. Adding it should solve the problem.